# Determine LAN Subnet from Device IP via Shell

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, nmap

Trying to create Zenmap launching script for a portable device. Built the follow Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Get IP
myip=$(ip route get 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $7}')
## Get LAN
lan=$(awk -F"." '{print $1"."$2"."$3".1//24"}'<<<"$myip")
## ZenMap Verbose Testing
#ZENMAP_DEVELOPMENT=1
#zenmap -v -v -v
## ZenMap GameShell
zenmap -v -n -Pn -O "$lan"
```

The idea is to get the active IP from `wlan0` and build a Subnet from it. For example, if the device has been assigned `10.0.1.33`, the script would find the IP and change it to `10.0.1.1/24` to use for scanning.

Results from `uname -a`:

> Linux clockworkpi 4.14.2-clockworkpi-cpi3-g638f2a7 #1 SMP Mon Dec 10 07:46:56 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

I see that `ip route` shows the Network Subnet, just not sure how to get it from the output.

```
default via 10.0.1.1 dev wlan0 
10.0.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.33 
192.168.10.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1 linkdown
```

Comment: please check your code at https://shellcheck.net and update your Q with any fixes required. (Include `#!/bin/bash` as the first line or whatever shell you are using). Good luck.

Comment: Does `ip route | awk 'NR==2{print $1}'` OR `ip route |  awk '/^default/{print $3}'` help? These assume the position of data you want never changes. Else we'd have to come up with a "smarter" test. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I will give it a try. The hardware and String position shouldn't change, yet it could in very rare cases, so this might be a workable solution. Will let you know.

Comment: @shellter I am also totally okay with another command that would return the correct detail.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but maybe `ip route | awk '/^default.*wlan0/{print $3"/24"}'` gets you a safer output. Good luck.